# Join issues - three tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've got two models, Category and Subcategory, a one to many relationship.

Then I've got a model called Notice that has a one to one relationship with Subcategory(SubcategoryId as FK).

Users adds subcategories that they would like to monitor. 
They get noticed when something happens within that subcategory.

Now I am trying to print out the information so the user gets an overview about which subcats are being monitored, like this:

```
(icon) Category Y
Subcategory - monitored
Subcategory - monitored
Subcategory - not monitored

(icon) Category X
Subcategory - not monitored
Subcategory - monitored
Subcategory - not monitored
```

Currently I have solved it by doing like this:

```
var SubcatsAndCheckedNotices =
                from subcat in db.Subcategories
                join notice in db.Notices.Where(x=>x.CompanyId == company.CompanyId) on subcat.SubcategoryId equals notice.SubcategoryId into prodGroup
                from item in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new CheckedNoticesViewModel() {CategoryId =subcat.CategoryId, Category = subcat.Category, Subcategory = subcat, Checked = (item.SubcategoryId == null ? false : true) };
```

Which almost works, the problem is that I need to print it out as I illustrated above and therefore need to make a Distinct selection(for the categories) and by doing that I am losing access to the other Category properties, for example the Icon property that I need.

I am stuck and knows that there is a better way to do this but I can't figure it out.

Here are my models in full:

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    }
    public class Subcategory
    {
        public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
    public class Notice
    {
        public int NoticeId { get; set; }
        public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }    
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you not just use navigation properties from category and print the category and then its subcatogories? Or just use a GroupBy on the result of your query to group by category?

Comment: I think you are missing the point here, I need to incorporate the user specific notices for the output(for each subcategory).

Comment: So do you only want to show categories and subcatogories where the subcategory has a notice added by the "Company"? If so could you use the GroupBy as I suggested instead of the Distinct?

Comment: Hum, no I want to show all categories and the corresponding subcategories. 
For each subcategory I have a checkbox that are checked or not depending on if the subcategory are present in the notice table for that user.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
var Results = db.Notices.Where(x => x.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)
.Select(x => new CheckedNoticesViewModel()
{
CategoryId = x.Subcategory.CategoryId,
Category = x.Subcategory.Category,
Subcategory = x.Subcategory,
Checked = x.SubcategoryId = null ? false : true
}
.GroupBy(y => y.CategoryId);

foreach(var Result in Results)
{
Print(Result.Key.(Information you want to print));
foreach(var CheckedNoticesViewModel in Result)
{
Print(CheckedNoticesViewModel.(Information you want to print);
}
}
```

EDIT: Nope maybe this:

```
foreach(var Category in db.Categories)
{
Print(Category.Title);
foreach (var SubCategoryNotice in Category.Subcategories.GroupJoin(db.Notices, x => x.SubcategoryId, y => y.SubcategoryId, (x, y) => new { SubCategory=  x, Notice =y }))
{
Print(SubCategoryNotice.SubCategory.Title + " " + (SubCategoryNotice.Notice.Any(x => x.CompanyId == 1) ? true: false));
 }
```

}

Comment: Sorry added x => new CheckedNoticesViewModel although your last comment suggest that my first idea was not actually what you wanted. If you want to print all categories and subcatogories and only idicated if they are monitored or not I would go with option 2.

Comment: Hm don't think option number 2 will work, noticeid and notice are not accessible through the subcategory model.

Comment: Can you make it so they are? Otherwise you can join notices in the first part I will amend the post if that is the case...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by taking another approach.

One query to get the checked subcategories, send it to view together with the categories.
Print out categories and subcategories and foreach check if the subcategorid is present in checkedNotices. Instead of trying to join everything.

```
                ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();


            var checkedNotices =
                from subcategory in db.Subcategories
                join notice in db.Notices.Where(x => x.CompanyId == company.CompanyId) on subcategory.SubcategoryId
                    equals notice.SubcategoryId
                select
                    new CheckedNoticesViewModel()
                        {
                            CategoryId = subcategory.CategoryId,
                            SubcategoryId = subcategory.SubcategoryId,
                        };

            return View(checkedNotices.ToList());
```